# Drupal hook before or after render() function

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view

I have a problem with my drupal page. We use the opigno tool (its a module to that allows to create course - nodes which can be bought).

Now we have a problem with the view of the course-node. Everything works fine until a user bought the course and the drupal commerce status is on "pending". The problem now is that the node is showing nothing except the title of the course.

I began to think whats going on and took a look to the view settings for the course-view. Nothing (no Permission was set, no filter criteria ...)

Then I took a look at the template override of the course-view. And then I saw smth ...

```
print render($content['body']);
```

Ah! A render function to render the content of the view. So I asked myself: What is in content ?

After printing out the $content variable I saw this:

```
Array
(
[body] => Array
        (
            [#theme] => field
            [#weight] => 1
            [#title] => Description
            [#access] => 
            [#label_display] => hidden
            [#view_mode] => full
            [#language] => und
            [#field_name] => body
            [#field_type] => text_with_summary
            [#field_translatable] => 0
            [#entity_type] => node
            [#bundle] => course
            [#object] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [vid] => 185
                    [uid] => 60
                    [title] => Demo Course
                    [log] => 
                    [status] => 1
                    [comment] => 1
                    [promote] => 0
                    [sticky] => 0
                    [vuuid] => 16e7999b-28bb-4f3e-8bed-54a21b17f398
                    [nid] => 176
                    [type] => course
                    [language] => und
                    [created] => 1406897520
                    [changed] => 1407145285
                    [tnid] => 0
                    [translate] => 0
                    [uuid] => 22baf19a-dc32-4137-b698-89f1bb4adc59
                    [revision_timestamp] => 1407145285
                    [revision_uid] => 1
                    [body] => Array
                        (
                            [und] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [value] => 

This is a sample course for beta testers, it will show you the structure of the courses.

Here usually is displayed the description of the course.

Please "enroll" if you want to see the contents of this demo course. 

                                            [summary] => This is a sample course for beta testers to help you see the structure of a course. Please have a look on it!
                                            [format] => html
                                            [safe_value] => 

This is a sample course for beta testers, it will show you the structure of the courses.

Here usually is displayed the description of the course.

Please "enroll" if you want to see the contents of this demo course. 

                                            [safe_summary] => This is a sample course for beta testers to help you see the structure of a course. Please have a look on it!
                                        )

                                )

                        )
)
```

Aaah! So $content has the content, but its not printed out with render()! But why ?

I searched in google for a hook which are able to "override" the render function and maybe deny the output when the user is on "pending". But... nothing.
I found this hook:

```
{hook}_node_view()
```

I searched for a using of this hook in all modules but when deleteing these functions from the modules did not changed anything. Are there other options to "override" the render() function ? Another hooks I can search for ? Or maybe you had the same problem with opigno ?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry - the problem was the Opigno Field Access Module. I deactivated it and it works like a charm.